# jsfiddle with knockout getting errors

Tags: knockout.js, jsfiddle

I can't figure out what the error in the console means when I run my jsfiddle.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rwa03vrb/1/)

And this is the beginning of the error:

```
    jQuery.Deferred exception: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return items }" Message: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return itemNo }" Message: itemNo is not defined

anonymous/<.value@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js line 68 > Function:1:58 a.d.value.init/m@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js:102:301 z.Qc@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js:51:391
```

That is all in yellow but there is a single red error at the bottom: `ReferenceError: itemNo is not defined`.  It bugs me that the console never gives relevant line numbers.  I supposed with libraries, partial views, layouts, etc, it makes it difficult.

Comment: You need `self.items = ko.mapping.fromJSON(items);`. See https://jsfiddle.net/rwa03vrb/3/

Comment: perfect!  Thank you for that catch, figured it was something simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that `itemNo` dose not exist in your foreach context and that's because you are passing the entire array of json as string so you need to parse your json string.

Try :
 `ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(items),{},self.items)`.

Example :
https://jsfiddle.net/rwa03vrb/4/